# Save and read settings value in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page in Windows Phone, where the user has to chose one value (a string) in a ComboBox item. After he presses the button, this value should be stored in the settings preference. How can I do this? Also, this value should be read in other page/class in the Windows Phone 8.1 application. I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
        private void save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;

        var roamingSettings = applicationData.RoamingSettings;

        // Create a simple setting

        roamingSettings.Values["surname"] = surnamesBox.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Have you debuged your app? Is this code invoked? How you load your setting?

Comment: The load settings are loaded with async method, which get the surnames from a json file, which is generated from a php. I saw the method is invoked. Are the code correct, for my scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to save the SelectedItem object itself. Convert it to a string:

```
roamingSettings.Values["surname"] = surnamesBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: That cast weren't correct, but the problem was there: roamingSettings.Values["surname"] = surnamesBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); Now it works !